# Paytm All in one SDK not working in release more or after publishing to Play store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, paytm

I have integrated PAYTM ALL IN ONE SDK to my android app. It is working fine in debug mode but in release mode it is throwing exception. There is small thing that i am missing because its working absolutely fine in debug mode but changing it to release it is throwing exception.

**Deposit Activity**

```
public class DepositActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mmbalance, mgateway, mtext_imp3;
    private DatabaseReference mmRef, mmtRef, mmbRef, mmcRef, mmcrRef, mmiRef, mmdRef, mmopRef, mmdbRef, yesRefty3, mmRefuc;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference, tdatabaseReference, yesRef, mmRefu, mmRefr;

    private ImageView mdep_back;

    public EditText mtodepo;

    private ConstraintLayout mcons_imp3;

    private String  TAG ="DepositActivity";
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String midString="MY MERCHANT ID I HAVE HIDED", txnAmountString="", orderIdString="", txnTokenString="";
    private Integer ActivityRequestCode = 2;

    public CardView depobtn, depobtn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_deposit);

        mtodepo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amountdepo);
        depobtn=(CardView) findViewById(R.id.depositbtn);
        depobtn2=(CardView) findViewById(R.id.depositbtn2);
        String mydep = mtodepo.getText().toString();

        mmbalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dbalance);
        mgateway = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gateway);

        mcons_imp3 = findViewById(R.id.cons_imp3);

        mtext_imp3 = findViewById(R.id.text_imp3);


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        String date = df.format(c.getTime());
        Random rand = new Random();
        int min =1000, max= 9999;
// nextInt as provided by Random is exclusive of the top value so you need to add 1
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        orderIdString =  date+String.valueOf(randomNum);

        depobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txnAmountString = mtodepo.getText().toString();
                String errors = "";
                if(orderIdString.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    errors ="Enter valid Order ID here\n";
                    Toast.makeText(DepositActivity.this, errors, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else
                if(txnAmountString.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    errors ="Enter valid Amount here\n";
                    Toast.makeText(DepositActivity.this, errors, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else{
                    int amountff = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(txnAmountString));

                    if (amountff <= 50000) {

                        if (amountff > 99) {

                            getToken();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(DepositActivity.this, "Minimum amount > 100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(DepositActivity.this, "Amount must be smaller than 50000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private  void getToken(){
        Log.e(TAG, " get token start");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ServiceWrapper serviceWrapper = new ServiceWrapper(null);
        Call<Token_Res> call = serviceWrapper.getTokenCall("12345", midString, orderIdString, txnAmountString);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Token_Res>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Token_Res> call, Response<Token_Res> response) {
                Log.e(TAG, " respo "+ response.isSuccessful() );
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                try {

                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null){
                        if (response.body().getBody().getTxnToken()!="") {
                            Log.e(TAG, " transaction token : "+response.body().getBody().getTxnToken());
                            startPaytmPayment(response.body().getBody().getTxnToken());
                           
                        }else {
                            Log.e(TAG, " Token status false");
                          
                        }
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, " error in Token Res "+e.toString());
                    
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Token_Res> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e(TAG, " response error "+t.toString());
            }
        });
    }


    public void startPaytmPayment (String token){

        txnTokenString = token;
        // for test mode use it
        // String host = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/";
        // for production mode use it
        String host = "https://securegw.paytm.in/";
        String orderDetails = "MID: " + midString + ", OrderId: " + orderIdString + ", TxnToken: " + txnTokenString
                + ", Amount: " + txnAmountString;
        //Log.e(TAG, "order details "+ orderDetails);

        String callBackUrl = host + "theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID="+orderIdString;
        Log.e(TAG, " callback URL "+callBackUrl);
        PaytmOrder paytmOrder = new PaytmOrder(orderIdString, midString, txnTokenString, txnAmountString, callBackUrl);
        TransactionManager transactionManager = new TransactionManager(paytmOrder, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void networkNotAvailable() {
                Log.e(TAG, "network not available ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorProceed(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, " onErrorProcess "+s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Clientauth "+s);
            }

            @Override
            public void someUIErrorOccurred(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, " UI error "+s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int i, String s, String s1) {
                Log.e(TAG, " error loading web "+s+"--"+s1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
                Log.e(TAG, "backPress ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransactionCancel(String s, Bundle bundle) {
                Log.e(TAG, " transaction cancel "+s);
            }
        });

        transactionManager.setShowPaymentUrl(host + "theia/api/v1/showPaymentPage");
        transactionManager.startTransaction(this, ActivityRequestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e(TAG ," result code "+resultCode);
        // -1 means successful  // 0 means failed
        // one error is - nativeSdkForMerchantMessage : networkError
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ActivityRequestCode && data != null) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, key + " : " + (bundle.get(key) != null ? bundle.get(key) : "NULL"));
                }
            }
            /*Log.e(TAG, " data "+  data.getStringExtra("nativeSdkForMerchantMessage"));
            Log.e(TAG, " data response - "+data.getStringExtra("response"));*/

            Toast.makeText(DepositActivity.this, "Payment Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
/*
 data response - {"BANKNAME":"WALLET","BANKTXNID":"1395841115",
 "CHECKSUMHASH":"7jRCFIk6eRmrep+IhnmQrlrL43KSCSXrmMP5pH0hekXaaxjt3MEgd1N9mLtWyu4VwpWexHOILCTAhybOo5EVDmAEV33rg2VAS/p0PXdk\u003d",
 "CURRENCY":"INR","GATEWAYNAME":"WALLET","MID":"EAcR4116","ORDERID":"100620202152",
 "PAYMENTMODE":"PPI","RESPCODE":"01","RESPMSG":"Txn Success","STATUS":"TXN_SUCCESS",
 "TXNAMOUNT":"2.00","TXNDATE":"2020-06-10 16:57:45.0","TXNID":"202006101112128001101683631290118"}
  */
            /*Toast.makeText(this, data.getStringExtra("nativeSdkForMerchantMessage")
                    + data.getStringExtra("response"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }else{
            /*Log.e(TAG, " payment failed");*/

            Toast.makeText(DepositActivity.this, "Payment Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isConnectionAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()
                    && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                    && netInfo.isAvailable()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ServiceWrapper**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ServiceWrapper {

    private ServiceInterface mServiceInterface;

    public ServiceWrapper(Interceptor mInterceptorheader) {
        mServiceInterface = getRetrofit(mInterceptorheader).create(ServiceInterface.class);
    }

    public Retrofit getRetrofit(Interceptor mInterceptorheader) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient = null;
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(1201, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.readTimeout(901, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
//            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            builder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
        }

        mOkHttpClient = builder.build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://mywebsitei_i_have_hided.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(mOkHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }

    public Call<Token_Res> getTokenCall(String code, String mid, String order_id, String amount) {
        return mServiceInterface.generateTokenCall(
                convertPlainString(code), convertPlainString(mid), convertPlainString(order_id)
                , convertPlainString(amount));
    }
    // convert aa param into plain text
    public RequestBody convertPlainString(String data){
        RequestBody plainString = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), data);
        return  plainString;
    }
}
```

Comment: which exception you are getting in live paytm?

Comment: Deposit Activity > private void getToken() > catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, " error in Token Res "+e.toString());
This one.

Comment: Test and live Paytm both are working in debug mode, but not working in release build

Comment: What exactly you are getting in this catch. What is there in e.tostring

Comment: This is in catch e.tostring - java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the new R8 code obfuscation. You need to disable it from your project by adding below line to the gradle.properties file -

```
 android.enableR8=false
```

Also you need to add below lines to your proguard rules file -

```
# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but After adding this solution,  it show 'Transaction Successful' after payment failed or successful payment. Without paying is shows 'Transaction Successful'. Please suggest me a solution for this also.

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote answer if it worked and add new question for new error.